# Rails access columns after using .includes method usind send()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**This is my basic query using includes =>**

```
result = Table1.where(some_condition).includes(:table2).where(some_condition)
```

**Now I can access table1 columns both ways :**

```
result[0]['table1_column'] ,

result[0].table1_column, 

name = 'table1_column'

result[0].send(name)
```

**All of the above works as result actually has those columns.**
**But table2 columns are only in memory by eager loading, so I am not able to access them by:**

```
result[0].table2_column ,

name = 'table2_column'

result[0].send(name)
```

**None of the above works, I need to access them using send**

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
result[0].table_2.table2_column
```

or specifically since you want to use `.send()`, then:

```
result[0].table_2.send('table_2_column')
```

### Explanation:

I am not sure if this is a standard, but as far as I know, you should not treat...

```
Table1.where(some_condition).includes(:table2).where(some_condition)
```

...as if it's returning a result like that in SQL (that is, a 2-dimensional table of results), but instead treat the result as Rails objects (models and not tables). Consider the following:

```
result1 = Model1.where(some_condition)
puts result1.class
# => Model1::ActiveRecord_Relation
puts result1[0].class
# => Model1
puts result1[1].class
# => Model1
# ...

result2 = Model2.where(some_condition)
puts result2.class
# => Model2::ActiveRecord_Relation
puts result2[0].class
# => Model2
puts result2[1].class
# => Model2
# ...

result3 = Model1.includes(:model2).where(some_condition)
puts result3.class
# => Model1::ActiveRecord_Relation
puts result3[0].class
# => Model1
puts result3[1].class
# => Model1
# ...
```

- AS you may notice `result1` is a "list" of `Model1` which is as expected, and same goes for `result2`. However, in `result3` notice that even though it is an "include" clause (LEFT OUTER JOIN), the results are still treated in respect of `Model1`, and not a "joined-columns" result.

### Alternative Solution:

Given that you want to use `.send()`, if you intentionally really want to do...

```
result[0].send('table2_column')
```

...and not the standard way which is...

```
result[0].table_2.send('table2_column')
```

Then you can use `delegate`. Be warned though that this is a global configuration for the model, and not a query-results-specific configuration.

```
class Model1 < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model2
  delegate :table2_column, to: :model2
end
```

Then now you can...

```
result3 = Model1.includes(:model2).where(some_condition)
puts result3[0].table2_column
# or specifically as per your requirement:
puts result3[0].send('table2_column')
```

Comment: got `NoMethodError (undefined method `table2_column_name' for #<Table2_name::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbaa092a7e0>)`  in both cases.

Comment: hmm if you followed my answer, I think that you should have gotten `<Table1_name::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy...>` instead. Were you perhaps doing `Table2.where(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access them using `includes` on the `Table1` object, to do so you'd need to write a manual select query.

If you think about it, you are telling AR to fetch rows from `Table1` (thus populating a collection of objects types Table1) and you want it to include in the objects columns from `Table2` which doesn't make sense.

If you absolutely need to do that, you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` to execute a manual query:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query 'SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.pkey = table2.fkey WHERE condition;'
```

Then you can use resulting set to to select your columns:

```
results.first['column_from_table_2']
```

Comment: that is what I understood, I was hoping that there is way to use .includes for performance issues.